# how to validate a random variable in jmeter, if it is unique or not for requests

Tags: performance, if-statement, while-loop, jmeter, random-seed

Here I want to generate a random 9 digit number, I have achieved it using a config element->Random Variable.
Now I need to check if that number is unique or not, so for that, I have used If the controller and passed a condition checking the previous response message is true or false, if the output is false, then it will again generate a Random variable and this time a newly generated will be passed onto it.

But till how many times I will check this using If controller, so needs an alternative solution for the same.
Below is the hierarchy of my test plan:
Random variable
Sampler HTTP Request(Here random variable is passed)
If Controller(Condition: ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==false)
Random Variable generated again
Sampler HTTP Request(Here random variable is passed)

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to generate a **random** number there is no need to "validate" it
- If you need to generate an **unique** number the number has to be sequential

You can generate sequential numbers using [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configuration element which should be set up like this:

[image]

once done you can refer the generated value as `${number}` where required

[image]

More information:

- [What is mathematical difference between "random" and "unique"?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/what-is-mathematical-difference-between-random-and-unique)
- [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: But I need to verify that it is unique or not after generating a Random number through Config Element Random variable, so for this can u let me know how to use while loop controller, and through it how to check for the uniqueness as its a Federal Number for a Policy, so it check its entry with Database for uniqueness, and then it is submitted

Comment: thank u so much for the solution, but here I m working for a banking site, it has a Federal number, so for filling a form it requires uniqueness, so generating series for this, there might be chances, it is found to be not unique.